# Moq throws exceptions stating that an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I am writing NUnit test cases. I am writing test cases to get some values. Below is my setup.

```
[Test]
public async Task GetGeographyList_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
{
    // Arrange
    var geographyBusinessLogic = this.CreateGeographyBusinessLogic();

    Geography geographyObj = new Geography() { Id = 101, Country = "India", Region = "APAC", SubRegion = "Asia South" };
    IEnumerable<Geography> geographyObjList =  new List<Geography>() { geographyObj };
    //this.geographyRepository.setupGetAsync<Geography>(geographyObjList);
    this.geographyRepository.Setup(
        x => x.GetAsync()).ReturnsAsync(geographyObjList);

    // Act
    var result = await geographyBusinessLogic.GetGeographyList();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

In the above code, `x => x.GetAsync()` throws an error:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Below is my implementation of `geographyBusinessLogic.GetGeographyList()`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GeographyEntity>> GetGeographyList()
{
    var listOfGeographies = await this.GeographyRepository.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    IEnumerable<GeographyEntity> result = from o in listOfGeographies
                                          select new GeographyEntity
                                          {
                                            Id = o.Id,
                                            Country = o.Country,
                                            Region = o.Region,
                                            SubRegion = o.SubRegion
                                          };
    return result;
}
```

Below is the implementation of the `GetAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Can someone help me understand this error and can someone tell me what I am missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `GetAsync()` takes arguments, and those arguments can't be omitted when setting up a `Moq` Mock. WHich is what this error is telling you. Practically speaking, try `this.geographyRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(null, null, null)).ReturnsAsync(geographyObjList);`

Comment: Hi zaitsman, I tried with null but same error comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill in all the optional arguments when you setup the mock. For example:

```cs
this.geographyRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Geography, bool>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Geography>, IOrderedQueryable<Geography>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Geography, object>>[]>())).ReturnsAsync(geographyObjList);
```